# CodeName One persistent storage

Tags: codenameone

My CN1 app produce file here FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath(). I can correctly read/write there files.

This folder name is like:- `file://var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D94F3BF0-821F-4B3E-B03C-981D883CFDCD/Documents/com.factoryname.appname.app/folder/file`

When i install a new version for my app on IPad, this part `(D94F3BF0-821F-4B3E-B03C-981D883CFDCD)` change and after i cannot retreive the needed files.

How can I guarantee that this part remains unchanged?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Storage class if possible. Also, you might add the build hint to use the "new" Storage location, ios.newStorageLocation set to true.

Comment: Yes. The `FileSytemStorage` works with OS specific location. Every install is in restricted OS specific location that you can't customize natively. It's a mistake to rely on a location as file system in mobile devices is nothing like filesystem in desktop OS's.